# Solution for Tag Wrapping in Notepadd++ is required

Tags: editor, notepad++

Greeting. I am using Notepad++ and i am trying to find tag wrapper for example i have a code

```html
<p>My Name is Pakhpalay Zamborday</p>
```

now i want to know is there any wrapper plugin or short key in notepad++ that wrap or surround the tags as per my requirement like i select above mention code and press that short key and next action ask me for tags with i want to wrap selected code. like i put article tag and press enter and the result will be

```html
<article><p>My Name is Pakhpalay Zamborday</p></article>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use snippetPlus plugin for this purpose. here the link and installation guide link:
[installation and usage guide link](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/snippetplus-notepad-plugin-insert-pre-defined-code-snippets/)

Comment: You can use emmet plugin too.

Comment: its good and i added this too but its not the one i am looking for. thumbs up for your suggestion bro